# onItemClickListener of ListView not working with RatingBar

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener, ratingbar

I have a list item click listener (`onItemClickListener`) inside the overridden `onViewCreated` method of a fragment. The method body is given below:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String uname = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("uname");

    list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drlistforhome);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Doctors doc = rh.drList.get(position);
            imgURL = doc.getDrProPic();
            docName = doc.getDrName();
            jobTitle = doc.getDrJobTitle();
            docSpeciality = doc.getDrSpeciality();
            docUname = doc.getDrUname();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), DoctorsProfileH.class).putExtra("img", imgURL)
                    .putExtra("name", docName)
                    .putExtra("title", jobTitle)
                    .putExtra("speciality", docSpeciality)
                    .putExtra("uname", uname)
                    .putExtra("druname", docUname));
        }
    });

}
```

The custom list view layout consists of six views: 4 `TextView`s, an `ImageView` and a `RatingBar`. The `onItemClickListener` was listening to list item clicks until the `RatingBar` was not added. But now that I have added a `RatingBar` in my custom layout, the listener wouldn't listen the clicks anymore. I am using a custom adapter to set all the views. Here is my custom adapter:

```
class TDsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Doctors> {
        public TDsAdapter(){
            super(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_list_view,rh.drList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, parent, false);
            }
            Doctors currentItem = rh.drList.get(position);
            TextView drName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drName);
            drName.setText(currentItem.getDrName());

            TextView drSpeciality = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drSpeciality);
            drSpeciality.setText(currentItem.getDrSpeciality());

            TextView drJobTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drJobTitle);
            drJobTitle.setText(currentItem.getDrJobTitle());

            ImageView drProPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drPropic);
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(currentItem.getDrProPic()).into(drProPic);

            TextView distence = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dis);
            distence.setText(currentItem.getDis());

            RatingBar rb = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            rb.setRating((float) 2.5);

            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

After running the application the list view appears fine with the `RatingBar` as expected, but the list items are no longer clickable. When I debug the app with a break point inside the listener, that break point never gets executed. What I understand from my very little knowledge about fragments, this is probably because the `onViewCreated` is expecting all the views to be created first. But as we can see, all the views have successfully been created. How can I fix my problem? Please do not hesitate to ask for more specific information.

Comment: try with adding focuable="false" in your ratingbar property

Comment: Tried that, no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in root layout of your custom row item.

Answer (score 2):

Write below code in your activity/fragment

```
 listview.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Also please add in your adapter row layout root,

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too. I will upvote your answer when I have 15 rep points :)

Answer (score 0):

ListView's onClick will not work If any row item of list contains a focusable or clickable view.

If you have your RatingBar's android:isIndicator set to false, then the RatingBar is focusable / clickable.

Set this in your RatingBar node in your xml:

```
android:isIndicator="true"
```